# Get data element from partial in modal, set value of textbox in parent with Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 5 with C#. I have a view with a button that calls a modal, which is populated by a partial view. The partial view runs a foreach loop to display a name, email, and "Select" button from a database of contacts. I want this select button to set the value of an uneditable textbox in the parent view. Upon clicking the "Select" button in this modal, I want the modal to close, and the ID from "data-contact" should populate a textbox in the parent view. I'm not very experienced with Javascript or Jquery.

Partial View

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("First Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Last Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Email")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.F_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.L_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email_1)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-contact="@item.Scholarship_contactID" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:onButtonClick(); return false;">Select</button> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function onButtonClick() {
        var contact_id = document.getAttribute.data('contact');
        $('#copyto').val(contact_id);
    }
});
</script>
```

And the modal code in the parent view looks like

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Select a Contact:
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Partial("ContactPartial", Model.partialModel)
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The textbox I want to be populated with the @item.Scholarship_contactID has the following code

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Scholarship_contactID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Scholarship_contactID, "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please select a contact", @id = "copyto", @readonly="readonly" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Scholarship_contactID, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The modal displays the partial view (with some formatting errors, but I'll tackle this separately later), but clicking on "Select" will only close out the modal without populating the textbox that I need. Can someone help me with the Javascript here? Again, I'm not a long time Javascript user, so I apologize if I'm missing something simple or using the wrong approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `onButtonClick` function should be outside the `$(document).ready(...)` to be accessed. It's because of the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) of the `onButtonClick` function, it can be accessed only in the scope created by the `$(document).ready(...)` function.